# Serve HTML files from inside WAR file with Jetty server and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, jetty

I have a simple Jetty server installation and run a WAR file compiled with Spring MVC. The WAR file is located in the `$JETTY_BASE` directory. `jsp` module is installed (`java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=jsp`) and JSP files are served well from inside the WAR file. But when I create a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/html")
public class HtmlHelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String getHtmlHello() {
        return "/html/htmlHello.html";
    }
}
```

And try to use it with `http://localhost:8080/web-app-spring/html/hello` I get:

```
Mar 20, 2023 2:06:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /web-app-spring/html/htmlHello.html
```

The file `html/htmlHello.html` is present in my `webapp` directory.

Is there a (preferably simple) way to serve this `html/htmlHello.html` file from inside my WAR file in Jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Spring to serve up static files. All you did was tell Spring to return a "view" called "/html/htmlHello.html".

You don't say what version of Spring you're using, but for instance with the latest: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources

Here's the XML-based setup we use:

```xml
    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static
        resource requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/htdocs/"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Answer (score 0):

add all your static files under resources/static/ as below

[image: SB-web folder Structure]

you can access the files as below

http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/index.html

http://localhost:8080/hello.html

use the below CURL to get the sample SB Project

```
curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d dependencies=web -d type=maven-project | tar -xzvf -
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm not using SB.

Comment: may i know which framework you are using.. based on the code snippet and log warning  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet i thought you are using SB

Comment: Ramkumar, thanks for your help! I'm using a plain old Java web project with a `web.xml` file that defines the Spring's dispatcher servlet. JSP processing is done by the Jetty `jsp` module as I can see. It's a study project with which I want to understand how the configuration may and must be done. Probably later will have a look at Spring Boot. As for now I wonder whether it's possible (and reasonable) for some controllers to return JSP pages and some to return plain HTML pages.